# How to determine if the user is on second floor of a building using google map without indoor map/floor plan?

Tags: android, location

I have an application which tracks user location, everything is working fine but i wanna know that if user is on second floor, I know this will not change lat lng, but is it possible without floor plan or indoor maps?

Answer (score 0):

Using the gps altitude (elevation). 
You might want to check this google elevation API, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/ but it is not accurate i wouldn't recommend it. Why? Simply because the indoor gps is not accurate at all and might even not work at all.

But what i am sure about is that you can use a motion sensor in the stairs of your building (for specified buildings). if you are in floor 1 and you go near that sensor it increments to floor 2 , if you are in floor 2 it decrements to floor 1 , and so on for all the stairs and elevators.